# I have no repeat on background image, but how do I stretch out the tile?

Tags: html, css

Hi Please do not bash on me or give me negative vote because I really did spend the time and trying to find the answer. From what I searched, this is what I have. I am trying to make a background image as my body but when I put no repeat on, it just a single tile rather than it stretching. Ive been trying to find a code that will stretch it out but nothing is there. I tried youtube and tried looking on here

this is my code

```
body{
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQoLWn_NOGkZO2BIkZyQud4OmegjxPMctGAZQAlKSf1DJvmsLyvA);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

my HTML

```
<html>
    <body>

      <div id="container">
      </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `background: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQoLWn_NOGkZO2BIkZyQud4OmegjxPMctGAZQAlKSf1DJvmsLyvA) no-repeat; background-size: cover;`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 1):

***[`Embedded Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Kw8r7/embedded/result/)***
***[`jsFiddle Demo with code`](http://jsfiddle.net/Kw8r7/)***

A better approach than using the body element would be to place a div that does this for you.

```
<head>
 <style>
  #background{
   background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQoLWn_NOGkZO2BIkZyQud4OmegjxPMctGAZQAlKSf1DJvmsLyvA);
   position:fixed;
   right:0;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="bacgrkound"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
body {
  background: url((https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQoLWn_NOGkZO2BIkZyQud4OmegjxPMctGAZQAlKSf1DJvmsLyvA) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
background: url((https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQoLWn_NOGkZO2BIkZyQud4OmegjxPMctGAZQAlKSf1DJvmsLyvA) no-repeat;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

This will `cover` your screen.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/IJObemU/1/

```
body{
  background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

you can remove the `fixed` when you need to make your background `cover` bot not on the body element (if you're applying the background on some element that scrolls with the page).